# How to use double quoted string for parseJSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Below piece of code is working fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var jsonp = '[{"Lang":"jQuery","ID":"1"},{"Lang":"C#","ID":"2"}]';
    var lang = '';
    var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonp);
    $.each(obj, function() {
        lang += this['Lang'] + "<br/>";
    });
    $('span').html(lang);
});
```

For the string "jQuery", I need to use "jQu\"something\"ery" to become the text as JQu"something"ery. But it doesn't work. Is there any solution for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Surely this is all theoretical; you'd never have a JSON string like that in actual code (unless in very specific circumstances) and if the JSON is coming from somewhere else single-escaping works.

Comment: Hi Juhana, as an example, I have an php array like this. array(1 => 'text"something"text'). when i encode into json by using json_encode, the output will be {"1":"text\"something\"text"}. Then I pass this to my view file and assign it javascript variable.

Comment: You don't need to do that: you can just pass the JSON-encoded string to a variable directly (`var obj = <?php echo $yourJSONvariable; ?>;`). That's the whole point of `json_encode()` --- it makes the data ready to be passed to JavaScript as-is.

Comment: it is not possible. then my javascript source become `var obj = {"1":"text\"something\"text"}` and then `$.parseJSON($obj)` returns null.

Comment: Right, the point is that you don't need to parse it, it's already a JS object! Just drop the `$.parseJSON($obj)` completely.

Comment: Hi Juhana, it worked fine when I just do as you told before. `var obj = <?php echo $yourJSONvariable; ?>;` Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the quotes in the JSON are escaped, which means doing some double-escaping:

```
var jsonp = '[{"Lang":"jQu\\\"something\\\"ery","ID":"1"},{"Lang":"C#","ID":"2"}]';
```

That JavaScript string contains this JSON:

```
[{"Lang":"jQu\"something\"ery","ID":"1"},{"Lang":"C#","ID":"2"}]
```

As you can see, the string value for the `Lang` property contains escaped quotes.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/EZABiweM/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/EZABiweM/1/edit)

Comment: Hi Crowder, Thank you very much. But the issue is I generate the string {"Lang":"jQu\"something\"ery","ID":"1"},{"Lang":"C#","ID":"2"} by php using json_encdoe and pass it my view file. there i have assinged it to javascript variable as this. var jsonp ='[<?php echo $jsonoutput; ?>]';

Comment: as an example, I have an php array like this. array(1 => 'text"something"text'). when i encode into json by using json_encode, the output will be {"1":"text\"something\"text"}. Then I pass this to my view file and assign it javascript variable

Comment: @user2909624: If you're doing that, don't use `$.parseJSON` at all. Create a PHP associative array with the data in it you want to insert into the script, then do this: `var obj = <?php echo json_encode(theArray); ?>;` (note there are no quotes around that). `json_encode` will ensure things are properly escaped. The result will be a JavaScript initializer, not a JSON string, and so `obj` will have the resulting object (in your case, it looks like it'll be an array).